# Google Analytics GA3 data extraction with Datafusion

Tags: google-analytics, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to extract GA3(Universal Analytics) data to Bigquery through Datafusion before GA3 is deprecated.
My issue is Datafusion has a GoogleAnalyticsBatchSource\Google Analytics 360 Plugin, which uses an authorization token to access Google Analytics Reporting API.

I need some help in setting this up as it does not use the normal Service account JSON key file.
Attached screenshot of the API key portion, at the bottom.[image]